# Split sting with white space and don't split if white space is between '

Tags: c#, string, split

I have a string

```
string text = "'test string' 'hello world'";
```

As you see I can't split the string with white space with `text.Split`

I try that and it actually work. Is there is a simpler way ?

```
List<string> Splitedtext = new List<string>();
bool InQuotationMark = false;
int Position = 0;

for (int index = 0; index < text.Length; index++) {
   if (text[index] == '\'') { 
      InQuotationMark = !InQuotationMark;
   }

   if (text[index] == ' ' && !InQuotationMark) {
      Splitedtext.Add(text.Substring(Position, index - Position));
      Position = index;
   }

   if (index == text.Length - 1){
      Splitedtext.Add(text.Substring(Position + 1, index - Position));
   }                
}
```

The Result That I want

```
'test string'
'hello world'
```

Comment: You should also include sample inputs where splitting _does_ occur.

Comment: Looks a bit like a csv where whitespaces are used as separators. So maybe one of the existing CSV parsers fits your needs.

Comment: No, I don't need a CSV parser. I am making A programming Language Parser like Assembly Language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non regex approach would be:

```
List<string> resultList = text.Split('\'', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
        .Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s))
        .Select(s => $"'{s}'")
        .ToList();
```

[Demo](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DreEsZ)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for **FSM** - **F**inite **S**tate **M**achine - you can put it as

```
private static IEnumerable<string> MySplit(string text) {
  if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
    yield break;

  bool isQuotationMark = false;

  int startAt = 0;

  for (int i = 0; i < text.Length; ++i) 
    if (text[i] == '\'')
      isQuotationMark = !isQuotationMark;
    else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(text[i]) && !isQuotationMark) {
      yield return text.Substring(startAt, i - startAt);

      startAt = i + 1;
    }

  yield return text.Substring(startAt);
}
```

usage:

```
using System.Linq;

...

string text = "'test string' 'hello world'";

// .ToList() - if you want to have a list
var split = MySplit(text).ToList();
```

[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lWzuMn)

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve similar behavior with Regex. Explanation for the given  regex you can find on https://regexr.com/

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

var regex = new Regex("('.*?')+");
var matches = regex.Matches("'test string' 'hello world'");

foreach (Match match in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(match.Value);
}
```

It produces 2 matches.

Comment: That Website is beneficial